# Forced Movement: Can a Halfling really pull a Dragon?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, forced-movement

One of my PCs is a Druid with "Thorn Whip". In our last session, he used it on a wall-mounted magic Turret Trap. Since the Power says "Pull the Target 2 squares", I ruled that he just ripped it out of its socket, disabling it.

Ever since, I wonder if there is no strength limit or some other rule that prevents such things. Extreme example? A Halfling with strength 8 is Thorn Whipping a Dragon or huge Stone and can displace it.

Is there a rule I am missing here?

Comment: Particularly for a magic power, one imagines that it might be the strength of the *vine* that is more relevant.

Comment: Sidenote to your question, you're looking for verisimilitude in a game that is designed to prize balance and combat crunch mechanics over any sort of attempt to simulate reality in a game. 4e is really great as a result, just don't worry about justifying how a character does what they do.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, there's no strength limit to forced movement. Pull 2 means pull 2, regardless of the size or weight of the target. This means your players could also use that forced movement on a gargantuan dragon - it's up to you to work out *how* that works, and really, if they're up against a gargantuan dragon, they need all the help they can get.

A lot of sources of pulling don't *require* strength, anyway. Lots of them are magical, and that includes Thorn Whip. Remember that the flavor text of a power is only there to help make sense of the power, and your players *can* have the spell work completely differently (PHB1, p54, on Flavor Text). In this case, considering the turret was *pulled out of a wall*, it may have made sense to describe it as thorns sprouting from the wall and breaking it up so that the bolts weren't fastened to anything sturdy anymore - then the thorns shoved the turret out. Maybe an entire tree grew from behind it to do that.

As a DM, I'd be pretty happy with what happened in your session anyway. A player who plays smart is a good thing, so long as you're prepared to let them surprise you. I would have done the same and let the turret rip out of the wall. Plus, it probably made your players feel pretty good accomplishing that.

### Resisting forced movement

If you really want to partially or completely prevent forced movement sometimes, you have some options. I advise you to reserve them for special occasions where it makes sense. If your player is using forced movement regularly, let them do that. If it becomes a significant impediment to your ability to challenge them, you should talk to your player rather than introducing forced movement resistance to most encounters.

#### Partial resistance

Dwarves have a racial power to move X fewer squares from forced movement they might be subject to. You may want to give this to especially heavy or sturdy things.

If your players are up against *Massif, the Demigod of Really Heavy Things*, you might even want to let him resist 1-2 tiles of forced movement - or half of it rounded down - just for the value of the players having some palpable feedback about his weight. He would probably have this as a trait that just passively provides this resistance.

#### Once-off partial resistance

In the case of a turret that's *fairly solidly* fixed on, you might give it an encounter power to resist 5 squares of forced movement. That way, they can resist all but some very powerful forced movement - but only once. Reason it this way:

- Weak forced movement (e.g. a *pull 2*) can be resisted, but it will tear the turret partway from the wall. The next pull/push/slide will definitely rip the entire thing off.
- Potent forced movement, e.g. a *pull 8*, will still be partially resisted - but the turret will be overcome and pulled a small distance from the wall. The sheer power of this particular forced movement was eventually able to dislodge the turret all at once, after a lot of effort.
- A source of massive forced movement - e.g. an explosion that pushes it 20 squares away - would naturally send the turret flying.

#### Total resistance

The *Restrained* status condition prevents all movement - including forced. Someone who's restrained also grants combat advantage and has a -2 to their attack rolls.

If something's firmly fastened down, you may want to apply this condition, but without the -2 to attack rolls. Granting combat advantage still makes sense, as the restrained thing has little capacity to dodge attacks.

Answer (score 3):

"Is there a rule I am missing here?"

Something that is firmly attached to a wall would generally be counted as "restrained" meaning that it can't move, but also can't be subject to forced movement.

As such, Thorn Whip wouldn't be able to pull such a turret.

Obviously, in this case, the turret wasn't particularly firmly attached.

With large creatures there is no special rule; presumably a brave adventurer learns to use the mass of large enemies against them (ie. you pull on the giant's ankle, and it stumbles forward before catching itself)